# como trasformar metodo en c# a metodo async c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

como trasformar el metodo a asincrono de manera que se ejecute esta acción en segundo plano.

```
public  void cargar_datos()
        {

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select id_zona, descripcion_zona from tb_zonas", conexion.obtenerConexion());
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            //con.Close();
            conexion.obtenerConexion().Close();
            DataRow fila = dt.NewRow();
            fila["descripcion_zona"] = "selecciona una ubicacion";
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(fila, 0);

            combo_zona.ValueMember = "id_zona";
            combo_zona.DisplayMember = "descripcion_zona";
            combo_zona.DataSource = dt;


        }
```

Answer (score 1):

La forma de hacerlo es mediante Task; y el fallo que se obtiene en los combos es porque se crearon en el hilo principal yno se pueden actualizar directamente dentro de otro hilo. Yo primero haría la función cargar datos de la siguiente forma donde retorna un DataTable con el resultado de la carga:

```
public DataTable cargar_datos()
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select id_zona, descripcion_zona from tb_zonas", conexion.obtenerConexion());
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    //con.Close();
    conexion.obtenerConexion().Close();
    DataRow fila = dt.NewRow();
    fila["descripcion_zona"] = "selecciona una ubicacion";
    dt.Rows.InsertAt(fila, 0);

    return dt;
}
```

Y ahora la función asíncrona que logra cargar los datos en otro hilo sería así:

```
public async void cargarDatos_Async()
{
    Task<DataTable> miTask = new Task<DataTable>(cargar_datos);
    // Iniciamos el hilo 
    miTask.Start();
    // Esperamos el resultado en el nuevo hilo
    DataTable result = await miTask;

    // Actualizamos los combos una vez terminada la tarea.  
    combo_zona.ValueMember = "id_zona";
    combo_zona.DisplayMember = "descripcion_zona";
    combo_zona.DataSource = result;
}
```

Comment: **1** Es importante tener en cuenta que el patrón `async/await` es una especie de todo o nada. Para utilizarlo en una aplicación que no fue pensada para ser asíncrona tienes que estar dispuesto a hacer todas las modificaciones que se desencadenarán. **2** Con el patrón `async/await` no hay problemas en modificar los combos ya que el framework se encarga de la sincronización entre hilos. **3** un metodo `async` no puede devolver `void` sino `Task`, la única excepción a esta regla son los manejadores de eventos.

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez La solución aportada la he testado. El punto **2** con la respuesta de Einer el usuario decía que obtenía error en los combos por lo que el framework no tiene nada que hacer cuando desde un hilo tratas de modificar un objeto creado en otro hilo salvo arrojar un error. Y el punto **3** lo puedes chequear, sustituye el DataTable por otro tipo de dato si quieres y los combos por un Label y haz tu mismo la prueba; a mí no me arroja ningún error. Prueba y comenta si te parece, porque si no se puede cómo es que ha sido posible?

Comment: Hola Antonio, por favor no me mal interpretes, no es mi intención poner en duda el funcionamiento de tu solución, solamente quise destacar algunos aspectos a tener en cuenta al utilizar el patrón `async/await`. La respuesta de Einer efectivamente produce un error al asignar valores a los combos, pero esa solución no utiliza el patrón `async/await`. En cuanto al punto **3** no da error de compilación pero puedes ver más [en la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types#void-return-type)

Comment: @PabloGutiérrez no por favor, estamos para aprender y esto de los subprocesos es un mundo. No te mal interpreto y sólo quiero entender y aprender. Gracias por tus comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza `Task.Factory.StartNew(Action t)` que acepta un action que lo ejecutara asincronamente:

```
public void cargar_datos() {

        System.Threading.Task.Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select id_zona, descripcion_zona from tb_zonas", conexion.obtenerConexion());
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                //con.Close();
                conexion.obtenerConexion().Close();
                DataRow fila = dt.NewRow();
                fila["descripcion_zona"] = "selecciona una ubicacion";
                dt.Rows.InsertAt(fila, 0);

                combo_zona.ValueMember = "id_zona";
                combo_zona.DisplayMember = "descripcion_zona";
                combo_zona.DataSource = dt;
        });
    }
```

Comment: Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException' en System.Windows.Forms.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario

Información adicional: Operación no válida a través de subprocesos: Se tuvo acceso al control 'combo_zona' desde un subproceso distinto a aquel en que lo creó.

Comment: al ejecutarlo me da el error anterior